Bootloader randomly jumping to address

For some reason here I'm very confused why its jumping to putsc16 after returning from puts32_done? I  Tried investigating this heavily but so far no bite, would appreciate some guidance. All code is here: https://github.com/amanuel2/boot_temp
These are the relevant parts:
Link
Code:
    movl %cr0, %eax
    orl $1, %eax
    movl %eax, %cr0 # (we are now in protected mode)

    # Far jump to stage2
    ljmpl $CODE_SEG32, $pmode_entry

.code32
.align 4
pmode_entry:
    cli # Make sure to disable interupts before protected mode or triple fault
    movw $DATA_SEG32, %ax
    movw %ax, %ds
    movw %ax, %es
    movw %ax, %fs
    movw %ax, %gs
    movw %ax, %ss

    # Set up a stack (make sure this area is writable)

    # Debug: Write directly to video memory
    movl $0x0f, %eax  # 'PP' in white on black
    movl $0xb8000, %edi
    movl %eax, (%edi)

Link
Code:
puts32:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    pushl %ebx
    movl 8(%ebp), %ebx  # Get string address from stack
    movl $0xb8000, %edx # Video memory address
    movb $0x0f, %ah     # White on black attribute
puts32_loop:
    movb (%ebx), %al
    testb %al, %al
    jz puts32_done
    movw %ax, (%edx)
    addl $1, %ebx
    addl $2, %edx
    jmp puts32_loop
puts32_done:
    popl %ebx
    leave
    ret


You misunderstand what gdb is showing you.  The "x" command does not mean "execute these instructions".  It just means "disassemble these instructions".  It hasn't executed anything yet.

I was under the impression that the disassembly shows u exactly what instructions it will execute since I have provided it the symbols? @TimRoberts

It is just disassembling instructions as they are in memory.  It just happens that putc16 is after the puts32. It does not mean that after ret the cpu will continue there. ret pops the return address from the stack.
